# Manipulate specific elements of an array

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have two vector signals with different lenghts in a simulink-model. Now, I want to add the values of the shorter signal to specific elements of the longer one. Let me explain that using an example:

Let's assume, signal A has the value [1 2 3 4 5], signal B has the value [2 4 8]. I want to add the value of B to the 1st, 3rd and 5th element of A, resulting in [3 2 7 4 13]. The corresponding matlab-command would be `A([1 3 5])=A([1 3 5])+B`.

The same thing should be possible in Simulink by using the [`Insert Zero`-Block](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/comm/ref/insertzero.html) to pad B to the same length as A and then adding both vectors. Unfortunately, this Block requires the Communications System Toolbox which I do not have. Besides using an embedded matlab function, do you see any other possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a selector block to emulate the indexing in MATLAB, I don't have Simulink right now, so here's a powerpoint version of a model.  In the selector block, you can either hard code the index you need, or you can feed the index in using a port on the block.

In this case, the model implements,

```
Y = A([1 3 5 7 9]) + B;
```

For more info, see the [Selector block documentation.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/selector.html)

[image]

Comment: This allows me to add to select some Elements from A and add them to B. But how can I merge the resulting vector with the remaining elements of A? Your solution would correspond to the matlab command Y=A([1 3 5])+B. But I also need to pass the unchanged Elements of A to the resulting vector, as in A([1 3 5])=A([1 3 5])+B.

Comment: Try using the Assignment block after the Sum block.  It has an option where you can pass in an initial output (in this case A), and then the values and indices you want to overwrite in that vector.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that such a block exists, it perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how insert Zero-Block pads the signals to same length. It's pretty easy to calculate indexes such as you specify.

I would do something like this:

```
a = zeros(1000,1);
b = rand(20,1);
indexes = round(linspace(1,numel(a),numel(b)))
a(indexes) = a(indexes)+b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not what I'm asking for. I already have a vector with the indexes. But I don't know how to achieve the effect of the line a(indexes) = a(indexes)+b in simulink without using the Insert Zero-Block (which I do not have).

Comment: ah - sorry. I didn't notice that you already mentioned an embedded matlab function.

Comment: Actually, I'm using an embedded matlab function now and it works fine. I'm still curious to find out if a "pure simulink"-solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your question, but what you are doing is not how to add two unequally spaced signals together.  The problem is you're not modifying all the values of `A`.  Let's say `B` had the value `[10 10 10]`.  Well, that implies that `B` has a constant value of 10, so we'd want `A` to just be `A + 10`.  Not `[10 2 13 4 15]`.

In general, you'd want to interpolate the signals to the same spacing, then add those.  First generate time vectors that correpond to the arrays, then interpolate the more coarsely sampled signal to the other.

```
% Let's say t runs from 0 to 100
tA = linspace(0, 100, 5);
tB = linspace(0, 100, 3);
Bi = interp1(tB, B, tA);
combined = A + Bi;
```

`Bi` is the important variable above, and with your example, it has value `[2 3 4 6 8]`.  The function `resample` is probably even better for general signals, if you have the signal processing toolbox.

So, if you think this more accurately describes signal addition, you know where to look in Simulink.  Look for Simulink resampling blocks.

Comment: I think your answer describes how to add two signals with different sampling rates. But that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I actually want to add two vector signals with unequal lengths for each time step. So, for a given t, I might want to add [2 4 8] to the 1rst, 3rd and 5th element of A, on the next time step I might want to add another value. Additionaly, I don't want to interpolate the values of B to fit the length of A, I really want to add just the specified elements. So, for the example above, I want the result to be [1 2 3 4 5]+[2 0 4 0 8] and not [1 2 3 4 5]+[2 3 4 6 8].